# Hotspot on my Sony Vaio laptop

Tags: wireless

I have a Sony Vaio laptop and I want to connect it to my hotspot on my Samsung j3.

Comment: Please try to put your question in a clear way, be detail oriented. Also, if You just need to have your laptop connected to your hotspot and you don't know how to go about it, try to make it clear in your question.
But nevertheless, that will still not be an Ubuntu question. And one of the things you can do about that is to use Google to find out how to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hotspot on Android phone creates visible Wi-Fi network.

- On Android side you should know network name and its encryption key.
- On Ubuntu side you should enter this information in NetworkManager:

  1. click icon [image] in top right corner of screen;
  2. then click on your network name and enter its encryption key).